# Summing two tables into one table in Jet SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, jet

Another SQL question if I may.

I have two tables (generated from TRANSFORM - PIVOT queries in Jet SQL)

```
Category  ID     Account     Jan     Feb    ...    Dec
1         1      Cash        10      20            30
1         2      Card        100     200           300
1         3      Savings     200     400           600
```

and

```
Category  ID     Account     Jan     Feb    ...    Dec
1         1      Cash        -5      -10           -20
1         2      Card                -100          -200
1         3      Savings     -100                  -400
```

Category, ID and Account will always be the same in two tables. There will be no accounts that occur in one table that don't occur in others. There may be NULL values in either table but there will always be a matching cell in each table.

What I would like is

```
Category  ID     Account     Jan     Feb    ...    Dec
1         1      Cash        5       10            10
1         2      Card        100     100           100
1         3      Savings     100     400           200
```

I have played around with UNION and JOIN queries but can't get there.

Thanks again,
Andy

Edit - The original queries are

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Items.amount) AS total
SELECT Accounts.accCategory, Accounts.ID, Accounts.comment AS Account
FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Items ON Accounts.ID = Items.accFrom
WHERE (((Year([idate]))=2013) AND ((Items.category)<>3 Or (Items.category) Is Null) AND ((Accounts.accCategory)=6 OR (Accounts.accCategory)=7) AND ((Accounts.curr)=1))
GROUP BY Accounts.accCategory, Accounts.ID, Accounts.comment
PIVOT Format(idate,'mmm') IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
```

and

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Items.amount) AS total
SELECT Accounts.accCategory, Accounts.ID, Accounts.comment AS Account
FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Items ON Accounts.ID = Items.accFrom
WHERE (((Year([idate]))=2013) AND ((Items.category)=3) AND ((Items.comment)='Monthly') AND ((Accounts.accCategory)=6) AND ((Accounts.curr)=1))
GROUP BY Accounts.accCategory, Accounts.ID, Accounts.comment
PIVOT Format(idate,'mmm') In ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
```

Comment: It would probably have been easiest to calculate the balances from the raw data and then run the Pivot.  But given that you have 2 tables, put them both in a query together joined by the first THREE fields.  Alias one table Cred and one Deb, then you have to manually do Balance_Jan: [cred.Jan] + [deb.Jan] and the same for every field

Comment: Easier than my suggestion: UNION the 2 tables together, then do a GROUP BY with each column of the month columns being a Sum to net of the credits and debits

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks. I have appended the two queries on the end of the question for your information. I have tried a UNION and just got one table following the other. Do you mind posting an example - I can't get it to work here. Thanks.

Comment: OK,you seem to have enough aptitude already (the PIVOT queries are fine) to solve it from here. I'm sure somebody will have provided an answer on here shortly but I hope you can do it yourself, it's the best way to learn!

Comment: I'm assuming you mean something like `SELECT accCategory, ID, Account, SUM(Jan) AS total FROM
(
SELECT accCategory, ID, Account, Jan FROM Query6
UNION ALL
SELECT accCategory, ID, Account, Jan FROM Query7
)
GROUP BY accCategory, ID, Account` which seems logical but doesn't work in Access...

Comment: Instead of trying to do everything in a single step you could create the UNION query to put all of the data together and save it as q_Union, then create the second step query and add q_Union into it and do the GROUP BY in there.  Or do you specifically need it all in a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach using the join of the 2 tables `deb` and `cred` is as follows:

```
SELECT cred.accCategory, cred.ID, cred.Account, [deb].[Jan]+[cred].[Jan] AS tot_Jan
FROM cred INNER JOIN deb ON (cred.Account = deb.Account) AND (cred.ID = deb.ID) AND (cred.accCategory = deb.accCategory);
```

This screenshot shows how the query is constructed:

[image]

And here are the results  (excuse the table formatting):

```
accCategory ID  Account tot_Jan
1   1   Cash    5
1   2   Card    100
1   3   Savings 100
```

Be warned that the `JOIN` is an equi-JOIN so it means the same number of records must exist in BOTH tables else you will find that credits where a debit does not exist will be dropped!  So make sure that both input tables are consistent with the same key values (the 3 `GROUP BY` fields in your earlier PIVOT query).

The alternative approach is the `UNION` with a `GROUP BY` to calculate the total from it.  I will paste that shortly.

========== EDIT ============

You can build this up in stages.  First I did `SELECT * FROM cred UNION SELECT * FROM deb` and looked at in Design View.

Went back into the SQL view and made sure the `UNION` query has brackets around it and `SELECT sub.* FROM` before the brackets and `AS SUB` after the brackets.

Then I modified the query to include the `GROUP BY` and `Sum(Jan)` bits.  The final SQL is here and a screenshot follows.

```
SELECT sub.accCategory, sub.ID, sub.Account, Sum(sub.Jan) AS SumOfJan
FROM (SELECT * FROM cred UNION SELECT * FROM deb)  AS sub
GROUP BY sub.accCategory, sub.ID, sub.Account;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will play with it tomorrow. Out of interest - is there any way the `[deb].[Jan]+[cred].[Jan] AS tot_Jan` bit can be done dynamically. I was also playing with the pivot using yyyy-mmm formatting - ie. creating one column for each month in the entire database (starts Jan 1996) - which would then mean this balance query would become huge.

Comment: You're limited to 255 columns in Access.  It's a good idea to understand your full requirements before embarking too far down this road.  It depends on the purpose of the data, the level of granularity you need and hence how it should be displayed.  I'd probably use `Year(transaction_date)` and `Month(transaction_date)` as separate columns, aggregting to the net amount per Year, Month, accCategory, ID, Account.  You may even want to distinguish Credits and Debits. Then you can report and pivot how you like but this a whole different discussion...!

Comment: Thanks. They both work fine. Thanks for the explanations as well.